# Passing an array of object to a Sub

Tags: arrays, object, vbscript, parameter-passing

I need to create a dynamic `Sub`. Bellow is a sample code of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
'File1.vbs
Sub MainProcess()
   Dim arrElements(3)
   arrElements(0) = div1
   arrElements(1) = div2
   arrElements(2) = div3
   arrElements(3) = div4
   Call InitHtml(arrElements)
End Sub


'file2
Sub InitHtml(arrEl)
   Dim arr, count
   count = 1
   For each arr in arrEl
      arr.innerHtml = "number: " & count
      count = count + 1
   Next
End Sub
```

But the problem is that it throws an error here `arr.innerHtml = "number: " & count` saying that object is required.

What should I do to achieve my goal and get rid of the error?

Comment: If `div1` is an object, where is the `set`?

Comment: @MCND - Nice I'll try that out tomorrow. thanks

Comment: Also, where do `div1` through `div4` come from in the first place?

Comment: `objEl` name would be more appropriate than `arr`.

Comment: @MCND - Hi actually your suggestion works. Set is the missing part :D. please put your comment in the answer so I can mark it correct. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @MCND answered my question. You can find @MCND's answer under the first comment in my question. He said that if it is an object there should be a set prefix. I might got that wrong but it gives me an idea..

to explain this.

objDiv1,objDiv2,... are id's of an element in HTML.
What I did is this.

```
'File1.vbs
    Sub MainProcess()
       Dim arrElements(5)
       set arrElements(0) = objDiv1
       set arrElements(1) = objDiv2
       set arrElements(2) = objDiv3
       set arrElements(3) = objDiv4
       set arrElements(4) = objDiv5
       Call InitHtml(arrElements)
    End Sub
```

It works!.

but I also found a solution for this, by using Array. here is a sample code

```
'File1.vbs
Sub MainProcess()
   Dim arrElements
   arrElements = Array(objDiv1,objDiv2,objDiv3,objDiv4,objDiv5)
   Call InitHtml(arrElements)
End Sub


'file2
Sub InitHtml(arrEl)
   Dim count
   count = 1
   For each obj in arrEl
      obj.innerHtml = "number: " & count
      count = count + 1
   Next
End Sub
```

I hope this help someone out there.

cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You are `For Each` through an array. Arr is same as ArrElements(0), ArrElements(1), ..., ArrElements(n)

So it's not clear what you are doing.

ArrElements is being passed to InitHTML. You call ArrElements ArrEL in InitHTML. So `For Each Arr in ArrEL` means first time through `Arr` is the same as `ArrEL(0)` (which is the same as `ArrElement(0)`), then ArrEL(1) the second time through. Arr is probably null as you are assigning uninitised variables. So you loop 4 times (if you didn't error the first) calling a property on a non existant thing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your answer. Can you please elaborate more, I'm trying to manipulate an object by passing it to a Sub as an array and manipulate it there.